# Xcopy display filenames only. Not full directory path

Tags: batch-file, path, directory, dos, xcopy

Any way when copying files via Xcopy (via batch) to output the filenames of the files being copied - or better yet, the base folder and filename - rather than the whole directory path?

The batch uses `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` which resolves to `C:\Documents and Settings\Username\` and then Desktop. Then that's where the folder lives with the files and directories to be copied.
Of course when it copies across you see `C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Desktop\TheFolder\SubFolder\filename.txt`  in the output window, which takes up 2 lines per copy and just looks terrible when you are trying to see where its up to.

All I want to see is `SubFolder\filename.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cd /folder to change to the source folder (or one above it), and in the xcopy statement, don't include the entire path.

For example, instead of this...

```
xcopy c:\tmp\q\z\*.* c:\destfolder
```

...do this:

```
cd \tmp\q
xcopy z\*.* c:\destfolder
```

And to copy from the desktop:

```
cd %userprofile%
xcopy desktop\*.* c:\destfolder
```

Comment: Bloody perfect. So simple. Thanks